# Response to cmd

Tags: python, rsync, popen

There are a large number of old linux devices. I am trying to write a program to automatically copy its configuration. shh public key authentication doesn't work, but rsync is there. I cannot send a password to the opening session. I'm trying to use Popen, but I can't seem to get the stdin sent to the process.
Security is not important in this case, because the network is isolated.

```
def syncdevice(ip):
    session = Popen([f'rsync -a user@{ip}:/mnt/usr /home/d400/ftp/{year}/{mounth}/{ip}/'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
    return session
syncdevice('192.168.0.1')
session.stdin.write('password\n')
```

I try other functions like "communicate()", but in not effected also.

Comment: Well-behaved software reads passwords direct from the TTY, not from stdin, so nothing is trying to read a password you're sending on stdin.

Comment: Anyhow, what's the underlying protocol? Is this rsync-over-ssh, or rsync directly over unencrypted TCP?

Comment: By the way, you'd better trust the values passed in the `year` and `month` variables -- because you're using `shell=True` a year of `$(rm -rf ~)` could delete files on your local machine. It's much safer to use `shell=False` and use an explicit argument list instead of a string.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's rsync-over-ssh

Comment: See the answers suggesting `sshpass` on the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RSYNC_PASSWORD` environment variable or use the `--password-file` option. The environment variable solution is:

```
import os

def syncdevice(ip, password):
    env = os.environ.copy()
    env["RSYNC_PASSWORD"] = password
    session = Popen(['rsync', '-a', f'user@{ip}:/mnt/usr /home/d400/ftp/{year}/{mounth}/{ip}/'],
        stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True,
        env=env)
    return session

syncdevice('192.168.0.1', password)
```

(note: your quoting on the command seemed off, it should be each token separately in the list)

Comment: `NameError: name 'RSYNC_PASSWORD' is not defined`. It's on a deamon and I don't have this option.

Comment: That should have been in quotes as a string. Fixed.